# How to start auto time out timer when my screen goes off and app goes to background cases and Need to stop timer when i click logout

Tags: android

i'm working with bunch of activities, i need to implement auto time out when my app is in inactivity state. my scenario is when i login my timer need to start if i didn't do anything after i logged in.

> my timer need to start with last interaction with application,
>   my timer need to start when my app goes to background and screen off cases, and also
>   my timer need to stop when i log out from application.

i tried with below code from Here only:

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {

    public static final long DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT = 300000; // 5 min = 5 * 60 * 1000 ms

    private Handler disconnectHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        }
    };

    private Runnable disconnectCallback = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Perform any required operation on disconnect
        }
    };

    public void resetDisconnectTimer(){
        disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
        disconnectHandler.postDelayed(disconnectCallback, DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT);
    }

    public void stopDisconnectTimer(){
        disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction(){
        resetDisconnectTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        resetDisconnectTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        stopDisconnectTimer();
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't starts my timer when my app goes background or app screen offs, in those cases timer stopped. 
Please give me ur valuable suggestions and help me for saving my time on things.Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Need to detect whether the app is in background state or not

```
@Override
    public void onStop() {
        if (Constant.isAppIsInBackground(this)) {
            stopDisconnectTimer();
            resetDisconnectTimer();
        }else {
            stopDisconnectTimer();
        }
        super.onStop();
        //stopDisconnectTimer();
    }
```

Here isAppisBackground() is the method for detecting background state